# java io netty how to get next packet from a client

Tags: java, minecraft

I am writing a minecraft server in java from scratch for private reasons.
I am new to the netty api so please explain how I can fix it

My problem is pretty simple my server waits for a connection then reads data from that connection but it never reads the then bit of info 
https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping
I followed that and everything goes well up until the request packet which my server never reads it?
I don't know what the problem is I think it's because its closing the connection but I have no idea how to stop that
Here's the code

```java
public class DataHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

    public void initChannel(NioServerSocketChannel nioServerSocketChannel) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Data Handler");
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] Read complete");
        //ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
         //      .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Data Handler active");
        ctx.channel().read();
        //ctx.pipeline().addLast("encoder",new Encoder());
        //ctx.fireChannelActive();
    }

    private int pos = 0;
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
       //ByteBuf packet = buf.readBytes(length);
       int length = readVarInt(buf);
       int ID = readVarInt(buf);
       System.out.println("[DEBUG] PACKET ID: "+ID);
        Packet packet = PacketUtil.createPacket(ID,length,buf,ctx);
        packet.readBuf();
        Object ran = null;
        //super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

}
```

There is some trial and error comments in there I did not know if I should have left them in

Heres the main class

```java
public class Server {


    private int port;

    public void run() throws IOException {
        port = 25565;
        EventLoopGroup mainGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup threadGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

            b.group(mainGroup, threadGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)

                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DataHandler());
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 5)
                    .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ,true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);


            ChannelFuture channelFuture = b.localAddress(port).bind().sync();
            System.out.println(String.format("Started on port %d", port));
            System.out.println("Registering packets");
            PacketUtil.registerPackets();
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

}
```